# Syntax to access a Bitbucket.org shared repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

This is probably really basic stuff, but I can't find it readily online. I created a repository under my user (joymaker2) and I go to get a copy of it:

```
   git clone https://joymaker2@bitbucket.org/joymaker2/catamouse.git
```

Now I shared it with my colleague, whose username is redeagle2000@bitbucket.org

Question: what exact command line will HE use to get it? The same? Or does he put his username in there somewhere instead of mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your colleague has access to your repo, then the only thing that changes in the URL is the username:

`git clone https://redeagle2000@bitbucket.org/joymaker2/catamouse.git`

The second "joymaker2" in there stays, because that indicates the repo's location instead of his user credentials.

BTW, if he goes to any repo on Bitbucket, then the URL listed on the overview page will include the correct HTTPS URL for him. (The SSH URL listed on those pages doesn't change from user to user, but he can also use `git clone redeagle2000@bitbucket.org:joymaker2/catamouse.git` as long as he's set up SSH keys appropriately.)

Comment: Thanks, Jim. That was simple and clear, and exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

He forks the repository to his own namespace and clone it to his local repo. After he pushes commits to his bitbucket fork he creates a pull request to your repo.

Comment: Forking may not be necessary if the colleague in question has write access to OP's repo. They could use branches instead for that.

Comment: Sounds a little bit complicated, either way. As long as we're taking turns, neither forking or branching is needed, just pushing and pulling, right?

Comment: Everything that will not involve forking will complicate authentication. So you just have to choose between 2 complex solutions.